# Default JUnit5 tests defined in external library

Tags: java, junit, junit5

We have multiple tests that are similar for a lot of projects(There are some team rules compliance architecture tests) and I would like to have a possibility to create some tests in a library and use it in other projects.

Example of such test: Test if there no usages of a specific class in code.

This library will be added to the project classpath and tests within it will run with project-specific tests.

How can I achieve that with JUnit?

Answer (score 0):

Two Options:

**Option 1:** Using JUnit (junit-platform-launcher)

Considering JUnit, what you are after is

https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#launcher-api

> 6. Advanced Topics
>    6.1. JUnit Platform Launcher API
>
> One of the prominent goals of JUnit 5 is to make the interface between
> JUnit and its programmatic clients – build tools and IDEs – more
> powerful and stable. The purpose is to decouple the internals of
> discovering and executing tests from all the filtering and
> configuration that’s necessary from the outside.
>
> JUnit 5 introduces the concept of a Launcher that can be used to
> discover, filter, and execute tests. Moreover, third party test
> libraries – like Spock, Cucumber, and FitNesse – can plug into the
> JUnit Platform’s launching infrastructure by providing a custom
> TestEngine.
>
> The launcher API is in the junit-platform-launcher module.
>
> An example consumer of the launcher API is the ConsoleLauncher in the
> junit-platform-console project.
> 6.1.1. Discovering Tests
>
> Having test discovery as a dedicated feature of the platform itself
> frees IDEs and build tools from most of the difficulties they had to
> go through to identify test classes and test methods in previous
> versions of JUnit.
>
> Usage Example:

```
import static org.junit.platform.engine.discovery.ClassNameFilter.includeClassNamePatterns;
import static org.junit.platform.engine.discovery.DiscoverySelectors.selectClass;
import static org.junit.platform.engine.discovery.DiscoverySelectors.selectPackage;

import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

import org.junit.platform.engine.FilterResult;
import org.junit.platform.engine.TestDescriptor;
import org.junit.platform.launcher.Launcher;
import org.junit.platform.launcher.LauncherDiscoveryListener;
import org.junit.platform.launcher.LauncherDiscoveryRequest;
import org.junit.platform.launcher.LauncherSession;
import org.junit.platform.launcher.LauncherSessionListener;
import org.junit.platform.launcher.PostDiscoveryFilter;
import org.junit.platform.launcher.TestExecutionListener;
import org.junit.platform.launcher.TestPlan;
import org.junit.platform.launcher.core.LauncherConfig;
import org.junit.platform.launcher.core.LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder;
import org.junit.platform.launcher.core.LauncherFactory;
import org.junit.platform.launcher.listeners.SummaryGeneratingListener;
import org.junit.platform.launcher.listeners.TestExecutionSummary;
import org.junit.platform.reporting.legacy.xml.LegacyXmlReportGeneratingListener;

LauncherDiscoveryRequest request = LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder.request()
    .selectors(
        selectPackage("com.example.mytests"),
        selectClass(MyTestClass.class)
    )
    .filters(
        includeClassNamePatterns(".*Tests")
    )
    .build();

try (LauncherSession session = LauncherFactory.openSession()) {
    TestPlan testPlan = session.getLauncher().discover(request);

    // ... discover additional test plans or execute tests
}
```

> You can select classes, methods, and all classes in a package or even
> search for all tests in the class-path or module-path. Discovery takes
> place across all participating test engines.
>
> The resulting TestPlan is a hierarchical (and read-only) description
> of all engines, classes, and test methods that fit the
> LauncherDiscoveryRequest. The client can traverse the tree, retrieve
> details about a node, and get a link to the original source (like
> class, method, or file position). Every node in the test plan has a
> unique ID that can be used to invoke a particular test or group of
> tests.
>
> Clients can register one or more LauncherDiscoveryListener
> implementations via the LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder to gain
> insight into events that occur during test discovery. By default, the
> builder registers an "abort on failure" listener that aborts test
> discovery after the first discovery failure is encountered. The
> default LauncherDiscoveryListener can be changed via the
> junit.platform.discovery.listener.default configuration parameter.

**Option 2:** Using Maven

Your Tests will need to belong to their own Project.

Example

```
<groupId>com.shared.projects</groupId>
<artifactId>common-tests</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

Then from any of your other projects which need to run these tests, add the dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.shared.projects</groupId>
        <artifactId>common-tests</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Then use maven-surefire-plugin

```
 <project>
      [...]
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
            <configuration>
              <dependenciesToScan>
                <dependency>com.shared.projects:common-tests</dependency>
                <dependency>org.acme:project-b:test-jar</dependency>
                <dependency>org.acme:project-c:*:tests-jdk15</dependency>
              </dependenciesToScan>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
      [...]
    </project>

Tests from dependencies

By default, Surefire will only scan for test classes to execute in the configured testSourceDirectory. To have the plugin scan dependencies to find test classes to execute, use the dependenciesToScan configuration. Dependencies can be specified using the groupId[:artifactId[:type[:classifier][:version]]] format, and must already be dependency elements in scope.

Note: Support for version, type and classifier was introduced in version 3.0.0-M4. When using earlier versions, Surefire will fail with an IllegalArgumentException if more than groupId and artifactId are specified.

<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
        <configuration>
          <dependenciesToScan>
            <dependency>org.acme:project-a</dependency>
            <dependency>org.acme:project-b:test-jar</dependency>
            <dependency>org.acme:project-c:*:tests-jdk15</dependency>
          </dependenciesToScan>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

> The configuration above will search for test classes in:
>
> ```
> All dependencies with the groupId org.acme and artifactId project-a
> All dependencies with the groupId org.acme and artifactId project-b and type test-jar
> All dependencies with the groupId org.acme and artifactId project-c and classifier tests-jdk15
> ```

Answer (score 0):

JUNIT5 platform launcher is easy to use and setup for scanning from the classpath. Thus you can build your various library tests into jar files and use them in several of your projects by appending to the classpath.

You could create say `librarytests.jar` starting with single class definition:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
public class Tests {
    @Test void tests() {
        System.out.println("success");
    }
}
```

Here is simple launcher for JUNIT5 standalone console application, and you could append as many JUNIT test libraries as needed:

```
java -jar junit-platform-console-standalone.jar --scan-class-path --class-path yourappjar.jar:yourappjardependency.jar:librarytests.jar
```